# Make Pair and Add Each Pair Individually in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am a beginner in Ruby Programming Language. So, I am  trying to get this output in Ruby. But I have no idea how to do this task.

When user give input like "123456789"
Step 1. I want to first make a pair of like this "12 34 56 78 9"
Step 2. Then add each pair's value individually like this "3 7 11 15 9"
Step 3. Then make a single pair of the values like this "3711159"
Repeat...
last Step. Then repeat the process until I get single digit number like this "9"

```
Input = 123456789
Output number = 9

Make a pair (left to right)     => 12 34 56 78 9
Sum the each pair individually  => 3   7  11 15 9

Again make a single number      => 3711159
Make a pair (left to right)     => 37 11 15 9
Sum the each pair individually  => 10  2 6 9

Again make a single number      => 10269
Make a pair (left to right)     => 10 26 9
Sum the each pair individually  => 1 8 9

Again make a single number      => 189
Make a pair (left to right)     => 9 9
Sum the each pair individually  => 18

Again make a single number      => 18
Make a pair (left to right)     => 9
```

I am using this code.

```
a = 123456789
a1 = a.to_s.scan(/..?/)
a2 = a1.map(&:to_i).sum
a3 = a2.to_s.scan(/..?/)
a4 = a3.map(&:to_i).sum
```

And it gives me this output

```
123456789
["12", "34", "56", "78", "9"]
[12, 34, 56, 78, 9]
189
["18", "9"]
27
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Comment: See `Enumerable#each_slice`, `Array#map`, `String#to_i`, `Integer#digits`, `Array#sum`, `Array#join` and `String#size`.

Comment: Shouldn't the next-to-last be "Sum the each pair individually  => 99" and there is no following step, 99 being returned?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I believe by "Then repeat the process until I get single digit number like this "9"" the OP means to *recursively* (or iteratively, depending on how you want to call it) apply the process to its own result. So, `99` is a pair whose sum is `18`, which is a pair whose sum is `9`.

Comment: Thanks, @Jörg, I'll fix my answer after 1 sleep cycle.

Answer (score 2):

You're summing the elements from `[12, 34, 56, 78, 9]`:

```
[12, 34, 56, 78, 9].sum #=> 189
```

which is `12 + 34 + 56 + 78 + 9`.

Instead, you want to sum each element's digits:

```
[12, 34, 56, 78, 9].map { |i| i.digits.sum }
#=> [3, 7, 11, 15, 9]
```

Which is `[1+2, 3+4, 5+6, 7+8, 9]`

Applied to your code:

```
number = 123456789
number.to_s                     #=> "123456789"
      .scan(/..?/)              #=> ["12", "34", "56", "78", "9"]
      .map(&:to_i)              #=> [12, 34, 56, 78, 9]
      .map { |i| i.digits.sum } #=> [3, 7, 11, 15, 9]
      .join                     #=> "3711159"
      .to_i                     #=> 3711159
```

Instead of `scan` you could also use [`Integer#digits`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Integer.html#digits-method) which returns them as integers right away: (in reverse order though)

```
number = 123456789
number.digits        #=> [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
      .reverse       #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
      .each_slice(2) #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]
      .map(&:sum)    #=> [3, 7, 11, 15, 9]
      .join          #=> "3711159"
      .to_i          #=> 3711159
```

As a loop:

```
number = 123456789

while number.digits.size > 1
  number = number.digits.reverse.each_slice(2).map(&:sum).join.to_i
end

number #=> 9
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken: the end result can be obtained by `a % 9`

Comment: @steenslag I think you're right. But you have to replace a modulo result of `0` by `9`, i.e. `(a % 9).nonzero? || 9`

Comment: @steenslag: Many years ago in high school, we had to prove that exact thing. I believe this was standard curriculum back than. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/99725/1937

Answer (score 1):

You could do that as follows.

```
n = 123456789
```

```
s = n.to_s
  #=> "123456789"
```

```
loop do
  e = s.each_char.each_slice(2)
  m = e.first.join.to_i
  break m if m <= 9
  s = e.map { |e| e.map(&:to_i).sum}.join
end 
  #=> 9
```

We can add some `puts` statements to help explain the calculations being made.

```
puts "s = #{s}"
loop do
  e = s.each_char.each_slice(2)
  puts "\ne = #{e}"
  puts "e.to_a = #{e.to_a}"
  f = e.first
  m = f.join.to_i
  puts "f = #{f}, m = #{m}"
  puts "Finished! Returning #{m}" if m <= 9 
  break m if m <= 9
  s = e.map { |e| e.map(&:to_i).sum}.join
  puts "s = #{s}"
end
  #=> 9
```

```
s = 123456789

e = #<Enumerator:0x00007ff9333befc8>
e.to_a = [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"], ["7", "8"], ["9"]]
f = ["1", "2"], m = 12
s = 3711159

e = #<Enumerator:0x00007ff9333b6580>
e.to_a = [["3", "7"], ["1", "1"], ["1", "5"], ["9"]]
f = ["3", "7"], m = 37
s = 10269

e = #<Enumerator:0x00007ff9333ad390>
e.to_a = [["1", "0"], ["2", "6"], ["9"]]
f = ["1", "0"], m = 10
s = 189
```

```
e = #<Enumerator:0x00007ff93339fdf8>
e.to_a = [["1", "8"], ["9"]]
f = ["1", "8"], m = 18
s = 99

e = #<Enumerator:0x00007ff9368c7300>
e.to_a = [["9", "9"]]
f = ["9", "9"], m = 99
s = 18

e = #<Enumerator:0x00007ff9368bd1e8>
e.to_a = [["1", "8"]]
f = ["1", "8"], m = 18
s = 9

e = #<Enumerator:0x00007ff933394458>
e.to_a = [["9"]]
f = ["9"], m = 9
Finished! Returning 9
```

Note that for the enumerator `e`, `e.to_a` returns an array of the objects that will be generated by the enumerator.

See [Enumerable#each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice). A small point: I have used [String#each_char](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) rather than [String#chars](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-chars) in order to produce an enumerator rather than a temporary array of letters.

---

One could alternatively write

```
loop do
  e = s.scan(/..?/)
  m = e.first.to_i
  break m if m <= 9
  s = e.map { |e| e.to_i.digits.sum}.join
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Two of the most important things in solving a programming problem are:

- Picking the right data structure and
- Picking the right algorithm.

In this particular case, the data structure is not very interesting, but the algorithm very much is. It is well known that the sum of the decimal digits of a natural number is the same as the remainder of that number when dividing by 9. And it is not very hard to prove that this property also holds no matter how you group, slice, and re-combine the digits.

So, we can drastically simplify the program by changing the algorithm to be just:

```ruby
def iterative_sum_of_digits(n)
  raise ArgumentError, 'Argument must be nonnegative' if n.negative?
  return 0 if n.zero?
  (n % 9).nonzero? || 9
end
```